# setState() clears the data in form element data flutter

Tags: user-interface, mobile, flutter, cross-platform, flutter-layout

I'm new to flutter and experimenting with Sateful widget. Here is the thing, In my UI screen layout, I have two different widgets

1. DropdownButton widget
2. TextFormField which holds card number.

When I was trying to update dropdown selected value to the DropdownButton widget, it automatically clears the text in TextFormField. Does it require to store text in global variable to restore again every time we call setState() method to update the values?

[image: Form UI screenshot]

Here is the code for widgets, 
**DropdownButton**

```
 new Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
              child: new Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  DropdownButton<String>(
                    value: _referPractice,
                    isDense: true,
                    hint: new Text(CONST_SELECT),
                    items: _stdCodesList.map((value) {
                      return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                        value: value.dialCode,
                        child: new Text("${value.code} ${value.dialCode}"),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                    onChanged: (String newValue) {
                      setState(() {
                        _referPractice = newValue;  // here I`m trying to update selected value. 
                      });
                    },
                  )
                ],
              )),
```

**TextFormField**

```
TextFormField(
                controller: _textController,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                style: new TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontSize: 18.0,
                ),
                decoration: new InputDecoration(
                    hintText: HING_ENTER_NUMBER,
                    suffixIcon: CircleIconButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        this.setState(() {
                          _textController.clear();
                        });
                      },
                    )),
                maxLines: 1,
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value.isEmpty) {
                    return ERROR_CARD_DETAILS;
                  }
                },
              ),
```

I understand that Stateful widget rebuild the widget every time when ever it calls setState but how do I persist the data for form data which is not stored anywhere yet.

Suggestions please! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you put your full code ? where do you initialize the _textController ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

With the given code, one mistake I can think of is creating `TextEditingController` every time.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  var _textController = TextEditingController(); //problem
  // build and return widgets
```

It should be in **outside** of `build` method. We can have it in `constructor` or `initState`.

If you have `_textController` outside **build**, can you add some more code?

Comment: Is this the best approach that each typing triggers the build function?

Comment: if you want to assign text to _textController then do in initState